# html img with 100% width, and clipped to parent element's height, which is not fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image, 'img.icon-avatar set within some html: http://jsbin.com/moqagu/5/edit?html,css,output

How can I force the image to be 100% width (as is now), but clipped to the height of it's parent element, so (in the example) it doesn't push the next panel down, and respects or includes the padding?

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="icon-avatar">
        <img class="icon-avatar img-rounded" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" alt="avatar"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">

          <h3 class="panel-title">
            Title
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Content
        </div>
      </div> <!--panel -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- row -->
```

css:

```
div.icon-avatar {
  ?
}

img.icon-avatar {
  width:100%;
  ?
}
```

Note that the parent element's height is not fixed, and will be based on other elements on the page, so I need the parent element to ignore the image when determining its own height.

Answer (score 1):

like that:

```
div.icon-avatar {
  text-align: center
}

img.icon-avatar {
  width:auto;
  max-height:90px;
}
```

Comment: But what if the divorce is more than 90px? The parent element height, and the row will be determined by other elements.